# Image TapGestureRecognizer not triggering in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I'm using Tooltips Effects (followed this [article](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/01/showing-tooltips-in-xamarin-forms/)).

There are `Help Icons` on the page, when I click on it, the tooltips appeared and if I clicked anywhere on the Stacklayout area, it disappeared, which means it's working perfectly.

There are multiple `Help Icons`, and I want that If I click on any Help Icon, tooltips for this help icon only appeared and disappeared the open ones, because now, multiple tooltips can be open at a same time.

For this, I add an `TapGestureRecognizer`, that when someone clicks on the help icon, close the open tooltips. But, I don't know why `TapGestureRecognizer` doesn't even trigger.

**.xaml**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mainstacklayout">

<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Tapped"
                          NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

// Code

<Image Source="drawable/help.png"
                    WidthRequest="20"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    effects:TooltipEffect.Position="Left"
                    effects:TooltipEffect.BackgroundColor="#222222"
                    effects:TooltipEffect.TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                    effects:TooltipEffect.Text="Tooltip"
                    effects:TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="True">

        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Tapped"
                                  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

// Code

</StackLayout>
```

**.xaml.cs**

```
public void Handle_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var c in mainstacklayout.Children)
    {
        if (TooltipEffect.GetHasTooltip(c))
        {
            TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(c, false);
            TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(c, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does the tooltip xaml work? if it is a modal with transparent background, then your recognizer is behind the active page, and for this is could not work.

Comment: something like this => https://i2.wp.com/www.xamboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ezgif.com-resize-6.gif

Comment: as u see, they all can be appeared on the screen at a same time, I just want one tooltip to be appeared on the screen, the other has to be disappeared.

Comment: ahh ok, well i didn't test this, just looked over the code but i think you might be able to archive this if you change `OnHasTooltipChanged` Method in your `TooltipEffect` Class.
before the ` view.Effects.Add(new ControlTooltipEffect())` check for existing ones and then `view.Effects.Remove(existing);`

Comment: I don't know for sure, but perhaps the TooltipEffect "consumes" the tap, so the TapGestureRecognizer doesn't see it. If you set `effects:TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="False"`, does the recognizer fire?  If so, then do that, and in the recognizer, set HasTooltip to True somehow.

Comment: @Isparia can't use *existing*.. wrote this `var toRemove = view.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ControlTooltipEffect);
                if (toRemove != null)
                {
                    view.Effects.Remove(toRemove);
                }` .. not working either

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve can't change the value of `HasTooltip` in `.xaml.cs`

Comment: @Stavrogin sorry to hear this, was just an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are multiple Help Icons, and I want that If I click on any Help Icon, tooltips for this help icon only appeared and disappeared the open ones, because now, multiple tooltips can be open at a same time.

According to your description, you want to make one ToolTip appear when you click one helpicon, then click to make ToolTip disappear?

You want to use `TapGestureRecognizer` to achieve it, but you have already implement TooltipEffect that call click event. It is seems a issue in Xamarin, more details can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8470)

But I see the sample have implement `ITipListener`, you can click ToolTip to make ToolTip disappear, don't need to use `TapGestureRecognizer`

```
 class TipListener : Java.Lang.Object, ITipListener
    {
        public void OnTipDismissed(Android.Views.View p0, int p1, bool p2)
        {
         
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

You have implemented xamarin.forms.view click event in PlatformEffect, it block TapGestureRecognizer. Can not find way to fire TapGestureRecognizer, but I find one workaround that you can take a look.

You can use LongClick to make ToolTip appear and use Click to make ToolTip disappear.

```
 protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;          
        control.LongClick += OnTap;
        control.Click += HideTooltip;
    }

    private void HideTooltip(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;
        _toolTipsManager.FindAndDismiss(control);
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;
        control.LongClick -= OnTap;          
        control.Click -= OnTap;
        _toolTipsManager.FindAndDismiss(control);
    }
```

**Update again:**

You can see I have add  `control.LongClick += OnTap;` and  `control.Click += HideTooltip;` on OnAttached method, it is same as `LongPressedCommand`, the article that you provided, its ultimate goal is to add longclick.

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("CrossGeeks")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(DroidTooltipEffect), nameof(TooltipEffect))]
namespace ToolTipSample.Droid.Effects
{
public class DroidTooltipEffect : PlatformEffect 
{
    ToolTip toolTipView;
    ToolTipsManager _toolTipsManager;
    ITipListener listener;

    public DroidTooltipEffect()
    {
        listener = new TipListener();
        _toolTipsManager = new ToolTipsManager(listener);
    }

    void OnTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;        
        var text = TooltipEffect.GetText(Element);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
           ToolTip.Builder builder;
            var parentContent = control.RootView;
           
            var position = TooltipEffect.GetPosition(Element);
            switch (position)
            {
                case TooltipPosition.Top:
                    builder = new ToolTip.Builder(control.Context, control, parentContent as ViewGroup, text.PadRight(80, ' '), ToolTip.PositionAbove);
                    break;
                case TooltipPosition.Left:
                    builder = new ToolTip.Builder(control.Context, control, parentContent as ViewGroup, text.PadRight(80, ' '), ToolTip.PositionLeftTo);
                    break;
                case TooltipPosition.Right:
                    builder = new ToolTip.Builder(control.Context, control, parentContent as ViewGroup, text.PadRight(80, ' '), ToolTip.PositionRightTo);
                    break;
                default:
                    builder = new ToolTip.Builder(control.Context, control, parentContent as ViewGroup, text.PadRight(80, ' '), ToolTip.PositionBelow);
                    break;
            }

            builder.SetAlign(ToolTip.AlignLeft);
            builder.SetBackgroundColor(TooltipEffect.GetBackgroundColor(Element).ToAndroid());
            builder.SetTextColor(TooltipEffect.GetTextColor(Element).ToAndroid());
         
            toolTipView = builder.Build();
           
            _toolTipsManager?.Show(toolTipView);
        }
    }


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;          
        control.LongClick += OnTap;
        control.Click += HideTooltip;
    }

    private void HideTooltip(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;
        _toolTipsManager.FindAndDismiss(control);
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        var control = Control ?? Container;
        control.LongClick -= OnTap;          
        control.Click -= OnTap;
        _toolTipsManager.FindAndDismiss(control);
    }

    class TipListener : Java.Lang.Object, ITipListener
    {
        public void OnTipDismissed(Android.Views.View p0, int p1, bool p2)
        {
         
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: hi, this piece of code is already written in my project..

Comment: yes, I want that if someone clicks on Help Icon, it opens tooltip for that icon and disappeared/closed the open one..

Comment: yes, this is working on my project too.. when I click on tooltip, it get close, also if I click anywhere on the stacklayout all of the tooltips get close..

Comment: I said when I click on the Help Icon not on tooltip or stacklayout, I want to close the opened tooltips..

Comment: @Stavrogin Implement xamarin.forms.view click event in PlatformEffect, it block TapGestureRecognizer. So suggesting to use LongCLick to open ToolTip and use Click to close Tooltip.

Comment: I followed this blog https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/ for LongPress Effect, but don't know why it's not working

Comment: @Stavrogin You want to add LongPress event into image? can you see my update, I provide one more easy way to add LongPress to open ToolTip and use Click to close Tooltip.

Comment: LongPress isn't working at all in my app.. I tried to follow this blog https://alexdunn.org/2017/12/27/xamarin-tip-xamarin-forms-long-press-effect/

Comment: @Stavrogin Firstly you don't provide some code about adding LongPress, so I can not reproduce your problem, then I strongly recommend you to take a look at the updated code, just add little code to add LongClick for your control.

Comment: Okay.. I've tried, the longpressed wasn't working.. let me try again.

Comment: I added above code for the `LongPressedCommand`.. it isn't working.. what am I doing wrong? and also where to add the code behind `LongPressedCommad` to make tooltip appears? thanks.

Comment: @Stavrogin As I said above, if you want to add LongPress in image, you don't need to use `xct:TouchEffect.LongPressCommand="{Binding LongPressedEffect}"`, just add little code in DroidTooltipEffect. Please see [this picture](https://github.com/CherryBu/gif/blob/master/16.gif), and see my update again.

Comment: when I click on Tooltip, `Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference'`

Comment: `_toolTipsManager.FindAndDismiss(control);` in `HideTooltip()` throw this error..

Comment: and I've looked into the gif, when u click on a Tooltip body it disappeared.. this is working already in my case.. I want that when I click on an Icon to appear tooltip, it has to disappear all the open tooltips.

Comment: @Stavrogin sorry for wrong link, please see [this picture](https://github.com/CherryBu/gif/blob/master/17.gif), Longclick to open Tooltip, click to close tooltip.

Comment: oh great, but why it crashed?

Comment: I just added the code in `DroidTooltipEffect` page.. is there anything i have to add in view page or anyother page?

Comment: @Stavrogin there are no any problem when I click icon or click ToopTip to close ToolTip, I just donwload the sample from link that you provided at the beginning, and modify code in DroidTooltipEffect.cs.

Comment: @Stavrogin Any update, if you still have problem, I suggest you can try to download sample from link that you provided at the beginning, and modify code in DroidTooltipEffect.cs, and try to build project.

Comment: @Stavrogin I download your sample to test, and I have crash in CameraPreviewRenderer, error message: Fail to connect to camera service. so I think this problem is not related to my code. Can you create simple sample that don't contains other code, just like the sample that you provided at the beginning.

Comment: kinldy pull the code.. i made the changes

Comment: Is the code now compiling or not (that "Fail to connect camera service" error)? earlier I commented out the camera code, it should work fine now.

Comment: @Stavrogin I do one simple sample about ToolTip, you can download it by [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/CSSClientAppsXamarinSampleCode/tree/main/tooltipdemo)

Comment: Hi, I cloned your project and compiled it, but when I click on `Show Tooltip`  (no tooltip appeared), nothing happens.. then I copy pasted your code in my code and again nothing happened (no tooltip appeared). and I didn't see any changes in your's code other than remove the color and background color..

Comment: @Stavrogin I have download your sample, but I need some time to debug.

Comment: @Stavrogin Sorry for late response, I have download your sample to test, there is problem because you add `Clicked="TooltipClicked"` for Button, deleting `Clicked="TooltipClicked"` , it works fine.

Comment: removed it and same issue (when I click on button, no tooltip) and sometime on pressing the button it throws an error on `_toolTipsManager.FindAndDismiss(control);` saying that `Java.Lang.NullPointerException: 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference'`

Comment: @Stavrogin I just remove three `Clicked="TooltipClicked"` for three Button, then it works fine,you can take a look this gif: https://github.com/CherryBu/gif/blob/master/17.gif

Comment: can you please push that code to git? thanks

Comment: @Stavrogin My company's policy  does not  allow  me to do this, I just download your sample, then deleting `Clicked="TooltipClicked"` for Button, don't modify other.

Answer (score 3):

1. The first test is to change the `XAML` where you declare each image,

to `effects:TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="False"`:

```
<Image Source="drawable/help.png"
                ...
                effects:TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="False">
```

If you do, does the recognizer work? If so, then you are halfway there.

Do that in the declaration of every image. This should "disable" all the tooltips.

2.
Use TapGestureRecognizer to turn one on (and turn the others off).:

```
public void Handle_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach (var c in mainstacklayout.Children)
    {
        // Turn off any that are on.
        if (TooltipEffect.GetHasTooltip(c))
        {
            TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(c, false);
        }
    }
    // Turn on the desired tooltip.
    if (sender is View activeView)
    {
        TooltipEffect.SetHasTooltip(activeView, true);

        // TODO: TooltipEffect source needs this method added;
        // it has to find the effect for activeView, and call its `OnTap` method.
        //TODO TooltipEffect.OnTap(activeView);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I set `TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="False"`,  unfortunately recognizer doesn't work.

Comment: If you remove ALL the `effects:TooltipEffect...` XAML, does the recognizer succeed in calling Handle_tapped? (test with breakpoint or debug writeline). If it still does not work, then it has nothing to do with TooltipEffect - binding might not be set correctly. Add to question the XAML or CS code that sets `BindingContext`.

Comment: I'm really sorry my bad.. now, the binding is working. when i set `TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="False"`, `Handle_Tapped` can be called. but I pasted your code, and the tooltips stopped appearing (even for images, where the `TooltipEffect.HasTooltip="True"`.

Comment: Now recognizer start working, but I replaced your code in `Handle_Tapped()`, and the tooltips isn't appearing.. any idea why?

Comment: @Stavrogin - Unfortunately my code isn't a complete solution. I forgot to trigger the tap, after setting HasTooltip. Might require a change to TooltipEffect source code, to make OnTap method public, so this code can call it. I think the one in article relies on a tooltip library written in java, maybe search for a different one, which is all written in Xamarin.